# A quotient by a discrete normal subgroup is locally isomorphic to the group itself

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a connected topological group and let $\Gamma$ be a discrete normal subgroup of $G$. Then why $G$ and $G/\Gamma$ are locally isomorphic?

Comment: The map from $G$ to $G/\Gamma$ is an open quotient map; now think about some particular neighborhoods in $G$...

Comment: A hint is that the projection is injective on a subset $A$ of $G$ if for all $g,h\in A$ we have $g^{-1}h\notin \Gamma$.